# Why is my metamask transaction failing even if I set a high gas limit?

Tags: transactions, gas, metamask, gas-limit

Below is a failed transaction. i set the gas limit to double of what it normally is, but it still failed. How can one figure out the correct gas limit, if the auto settings don't even work.

Why does this even happen?

[image]

Comment: I set the GWEI to 5 instead of 10 and set gas limit to 200K and it worked. The fee was 0.00019756 ETH ($.12)

Comment: Do you have at least `1.0000000118536` ethers in your account?

Comment: yes i do. i have more than 1.

Comment: Do you have a transaction hash? Do you have the source of the target contract? Wallets usually simulate the transaction being executed to calculate gas fee. It is possible that there are changes in the target contract before the transaction is mined that render the gas calculation invalid but it depends on the target contract behavior.

Comment: its a basic contract sending exchange tokens. nothing fancy.